# antlr4 all words except the operators

Tags: antlr4

```
grammar TestGrammar;
AND : 'AND' ;
OR  : 'OR'|',' ;
NOT : 'NOT' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
DQUOTE : '"' ;
WORD : [a-z0-9._#+=]+(' '[a-z0-9._#+=]+)* ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

quotedword : DQUOTE WORD DQUOTE;
expression
    : LPAREN expression+ RPAREN
    | expression (AND expression)+
    | expression (OR​ expression)+
    | expression (NOT​ expression)+
    | NOT expression+
    | quotedword
    | WORD;
```

I've managed to implement the above grammar for antlr4.
I've got a long way to go but for now my question is,
how can I make `WORD` generic? Basically I want this `[a-z0-9._#+=]` to be anything except the operators (`AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `LPAREN`, `RPAREN`, `DQUOTE`, `SPACE`).

Comment: Maybe you provide the purpose of your grammar? Your WORDs may contain spaces (but not other white space). Wouldnt it be better if you did not allow WORD as expression but WORD+ (and define WORD to be `[a-z0-9._#+=]+`.

Comment: That's debatable. The thing is that space can have multiple interpretations. If inside double quotes treat it as part of the quoted phrase. If outside of double quotes and not before a parenthesis use it to group the tokens. If before a parenthesis use it as an AND. This grammar is my first attempt and seems to be ok for all the possible input I may have. I'll try what you suggested. Thank you

Comment: Ok, a very common solution to your problem is, that quotedword is a lexer token (e.g. [Java String Literals](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaLexer.g4) in Java). If you do so, you can use WORD+ for sequences of words and QUOTEDWORD as string literal.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide an example even if incomplete as an answer? That way I can use it as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar;
...
WORD : Letter+;
QUOTEDWORD : '"' (~["\\\r\n])* '"' // disallow quotes, backslashes and crlf in literals
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment Letter : 
    [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0x7F
  | ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF] // covers all characters above 0x7F which are not a surrogate
  | [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
;

expression:
  ...
  | QUOTEDWORD
  | WORD+;
```

Maybe you want to use escape sequences in `QUOTEDWORD`, then look in [this example](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaLexer.g4) how to do this.

This grammar allows you:

- to have quoted words interpreted as string literals (preserving all spaces within)
- to have multiple words separated by whitespace (which is ignored)

Comment: This seems to be a finer solution than mine, but the problem remains. WORD will still be `a-z0-9._#+=` I need it to be any character (for utf8 characters mostly)

Comment: Ok, I did not recognize that this was part of the problem. I changed the grammar in an appropriate way. Now Words can contain ordinary letters, but not whitespaces - copied from the example I already referenced. Including whitespace will not work, but it makes no sense with my solution (only for QUOTEDWORD).

Comment: Thank you @CoronA I'll try this and get back with feedback

Comment: Works like a charm, already upvoted and now accepted. I didn't think to check the java grammar. It was very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The lexer will use the first rule that can match the given input. Only if that rule can't match it, it will try the next one.

Therefore you can make your `WORD` rule generic by using this grammar:

```
AND : 'AND' ;
OR  : 'OR'|',' ;
NOT : 'NOT' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
DQUOTE : '"' ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
WORD: .+? ;
```

Make sure to use the non-greedy operator `?` in this case becaue otherwise once invoked the `WORD` rule will consume all following input.

As `WORD` is specified last, input will only be tried to be consumed by it if all previous lexer rules (all that have been defined above in the source code) have failed.

EDIT: If you don't want your `WORD` rule to match *any* input then you just have to modify the rule I provided. But the essence of my answer is that in the lexer you don't have to worry about two rules potentially matching the same input as long as you got the order in the source code right.

Comment: Upvoting for now. I'll try your suggestion and come back with feedback. This will change other parts of the grammar as well but I'm fine with that. Thank you!

Comment: `WORD: .?+` this is wrong. 1. it doesn't have a semicolon, 2. `.?+` the plugin shows that this is not valid. 3. when I run it through the preview intellij hung...

Comment: Oh yeah I switched the order... See my edited answer